# Zend Framework: Is it possible to create nested array from the list array?

Tags: arrays, zend-framework, nested, zend-navigation

For example, I have an array:

```
array(
   array('id' => 1, 'parent' => 0),
   array('id' => 5, 'parent' => 0),
   array('id' => 3, 'parent' => 4),
   array('id' => 4, 'parent' => 6),
   array('id' => 6, 'parent' => 1),
);
```

How generate nested array without using recursion (via Zend_Navigation) to get this one?

```
array(
    'id' => 0,
    'pages' => array(
                     array('id => 1,
                           'pages' => array('id' => 6, 
                                            'pages' => array('id' => 4,
                                                             'pages' => array('id'=>3, 'pages' => null)
                                                             )
                                             )
                            )
                     ),
               array(
                      array('id' => 5, 'pages => null)
               )
     )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$pages = array(
   array('id' => 1, 'parent' => 0),
   array('id' => 5, 'parent' => 0),
   array('id' => 3, 'parent' => 4),
   array('id' => 4, 'parent' => 6),
   array('id' => 6, 'parent' => 1),
);
$container = new Zend_Navigation();
$container->addPage(new Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri(array(
    'label' => 'root',
    'uri' => '',
    'visible' => false,
    'id' => 0,
)));

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $found = $container->findById($page['parent']);
    $found->addPage(
        Zend_Navigation_Page::factory(array(
            'id' => $page['id'],
            'label' => 'label' . $page['id']
        )));
}
var_dump($container->toArray());
```

Comment: Excellent! I just added controller name (or action or module) as a parameter to Zend_Navigation_Page::factory to avoid error. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SMka - This would only work if the children were 'one level deep'. Is there any way to expand on it so it would work to the 'nth' degree?